# js/jquery Async Content Overwrites Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

ive ran into the following Problem and maybe someone can give me a little advice or a way around this. I have the following Problem:

A Partner of my Page provided me with a Code that i should use on my Page, which writes some Content to my Page that i really want.

Unfortunately this Content is only relevant to People living in a certain region.
So i am using the service of an ip-api which returns the region the current user is in and lets me work with that. This is done with a jsonp ajax call.
If the Person is in the right Region the Code should be executed, if he is not, it shouldnt.

The Problem is that the code to be executed contains a document.write. So if i call that code inside of the ip-api callback the document is allready loaded and the document.write will overwrite my page.

So the big Question is: Is there a way to capture the document.write output into a variable like with PHPs output buffer? Or maybe some way to overwrite the content of an iframe instead of the whole Page? Anything that prevents the document.write from overwriting the page and redirects its output into a part of my page would be sufficient.

Thanks for your time :)

PS: this is the code im talking about:

```js
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ip-api.com/json/",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( response ) {
                if(
                        response["city"]=="Hamburg" ||
                        response["region"]=="SH" ||
                        response["region"]=="NW"

                ){
                    document.write("Some Content here");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`document.write("Some Content here");`

with

`$('#my-container').html('Some content here');`

Comment: Corrilld, note that you must *have* such a div sitting on your page for the content to be injected into: `<div id="my_container"></div>`. Or, you can specify the `id` of an existing div *and the content injected by ajax will overwrite the content of the specified div*.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, since the Code is not mine and i cannot change it (it is loaded directly from my Partner). And he wont change his Code for me, i dont have enought influence for that ;)

Comment: Then you need to move on and find a competent partner